# WordPress PHP 'printf' giving two values

Tags: php, html, wordpress, buddypress

I'm running WordPress 4.9.6 with BuddyPress and BuddyPress XProfile plugin.
XProfile is getting the users location and returning it as a hyperlink in their profile to search the rest of the site with the same location tag.

The issue I'm getting is the PHP script is returning the location plus a number which changes between 69, 76, and 22.

This is the code that I'm running to get the location:

```
    /**
     * Modify the appearance of value.
     *
     * @param  string $field_value Original value of field.
     * @param  int    $field_id Id of field.
     *
     * @return string   Value formatted
     */
    public static function display_filter( $field_value, $field_id = 0 ) {

        if ( empty( $field_value ) ) {
            return;
        }

        $term_id = absint( $field_value );
        $tax = self::get_selected_taxonomy( $field_id );

        $term = get_term( $term_id, $tax );
        if ( ! $term || is_wp_error( $term ) ) {
            return '';
        }

        return  printf( '<a href="%1$s">%2$s</a>', esc_url( get_term_link( $term, $tax ) ), esc_html( $term->name ) );

    }

    /**
     * Get the terms content.
     *
     * @param int $field_id field id.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public static function get_selected_taxonomy( $field_id ) {

        if ( ! $field_id ) {
            return '';
        }

        return bp_xprofile_get_meta( $field_id, 'field', 'selected_taxonomy',  true );
    }
}
```

I changed from sprintf to printf as it was returning the full HTML code. 
Since changing to printf, this error has occurred.

What part do I need to amend or remove to lose the number tag being generated, please?

[This is a screenshot of the tag plus the number below it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wp9JS.png)

Comment: printf outputs the string to the browser immediately, and then returns the length of that string as a number, which is why the number you’re seeing changes. sprintf returns the string itself, which seems like what is needed here, although you’ve already tried this?

Comment: The original was sprintf which gave the raw html with &gt; instead of a greater than sign, - thats why I changed it.  Tried changing it to fix the > problem but it stopped returning a value all together